# The code runs successfully but no graphs as an output

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to replicate the work of [Nonlinear-Infection by Fabian Dablander](https://fabiandablander.com/r/Nonlinear-Infection.html) in the case of Pakistan. But when I run the codes below then it doesn't make any graph as an output"

```
plot_SIR <- function(res, main = '') {
cols <- brewer.pal(3, 'Set1')
matplot(
res, type = 'l', col = cols, axes = FALSE, lty = 1, lwd = 2,
ylab = 'Subpopulations(t)', xlab = 'Time t', xlim = c(0, 4000),
ylim = c(0, 1), main = main, cex.main = 1.75, cex.lab = 1.5,
font.main = 1, xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i'
)

axis(1, cex.axis = 1.25)
axis(2, las = 2, cex.axis = 1.25)
legend(
3000, 0.65, col = cols, legend = c('S', 'I', 'R'),
lty = 1, lwd = 2, bty = 'n', cex = 1.5
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick look, you need to run the other function to get the param: res, then stick it inside the original function just as you described in the post:

```
solve_SIR <- function(S0, I0, beta = 1, gamma = 1, delta_t = 0.01, times = 8000) {
  res <- matrix(
    NA, nrow = times, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, c('S', 'I', 'R', 'Time'))
  )
  res[1, ] <- c(S0, I0, 1 - S0 - I0, delta_t)

  dS <- function(S, I) -beta * I * S
  dI <- function(S, I)  beta * I * S - gamma * I

  for (i in seq(2, times)) {
    S <- res[i-1, 1]
    I <- res[i-1, 2]

    res[i, 1] <- res[i-1, 1] + delta_t * dS(S, I)
    res[i, 2] <- res[i-1, 2] + delta_t * dI(S, I)
    res[i, 4] <- delta_t * i
  }

  res[, 3] <- 1 - res[, 1] - res[, 2]
  res
}
```

use function to gen param input and choosing random values for S0 and I0 this will output the graph you desired.

```
plot_SIR(solve_SIR(0.95, 0.05))
```

Comment: Yes your codes worked however, I also loaded the  ** library(RColorBrewer)** for the `brewer.pal` function.

Comment: Yes, anytime you are working with packages you need to load them. Running library() loads and attached the package to the source path. Alternatively, you could load the package directly without library with RColorBrewer::<function>